# How can I keep an old value in select option after error in validation? - laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have this selector option, I'm trying to keep an old value when validation fails in laravel validation, I tried this.

```
<select name="type" id="type" class="form-control @error('type') is-invalid @enderror"
                                                required autocomplete="type">
                                            @foreach ($mailMessageTypes as $value =>$label)
                                                <option value="{{$value}}" {{ old('type') === $value ? 'selected' : ''}}>{{$label}}</option>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </select>
```

for example in the screenshot bellow it works on my inputs fields

input example:

```
<input id="from_value" type="number" min="0"
                                               class="form-control @error('from_value') is-invalid @enderror"
                                               name="from_value"
                                               value="{{ old('from_value') }}" required autocomplete="from_value"
                                               autofocus>
                                        @error('from_value')
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                        @enderror
```

[image]

How can I do it?
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved:

```
<select name="type" id="type" class="form-control" required>
                                                <option></option>
                                            @foreach ($mailMessageTypes as $value =>$label)
                                                <option value="{{$value}}" {{old ('type') == $value ? 'selected' : ''}}>{{$label}}</option>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `{{ old('type')}}` like that:

```
<select value="{{ old('type')}}" name="type" id="type" class="form-control @error('type') is-invalid @enderror required autocomplete="type"></select>
```

Comment: not works for me :(